# How to add Pull to refresh feature to Flutter Webview without any problem?

Tags: flutter, webview, pull-to-refresh

How to add Pull to refresh feature to Flutter Webview without any problem?
I've been struggling for 2 days.
Here is the whole code but it doesn't work correctly. Could you please help?
What is the best practice to give refresh feature to webview?
This code I wrote gives an error, the application closes

.....
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
WebViewController? _webviewController;

```
return SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      actions: [],
    ),
    body: RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: () {
        return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
          _webviewController!.reload();
        });
      },
      child: Expanded(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: heights,
                child: WebView(
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                  initialUrl: "https://flutter.dev/",
                  // WebviewControlleri burada tanimliyoruz
                  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                    _webviewController = webViewController;
                  },
                  onPageFinished: (content) async {
                    var _heights = double.parse(await _webviewController!
                        .evaluateJavascript(
                            "document.documentElement.scrollHeight"));
                    heights = _heights;

                    setState(() {});
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
      color: Colors.amber,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              // Geri donecek bir sey varmi kontrol ediyoruz
              if (await _webviewController!.canGoBack()) {
                // Varsa geri donuyoruz
                _webviewController!.goBack();
              } else {
                // Yoksa ekrana mesaj gosteriyoruz
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    SnackBar(content: Text("Geri donecek bir sey yok")));
              }
            },
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_left,
              size: 50,
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              // Ileriye gidecek bir sey varmi kontrol ediyoruz
              if (await _webviewController!.canGoForward()) {
                // Varsa ileri gidiyoruz
                _webviewController!.goForward();
              } else {
                // Yoksa ekrana mesaj gosteriyoruz
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    SnackBar(content: Text("Ileri gidecek bir sey yok")));
              }
            },
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_right,
              size: 50,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Comment: Please format properly your code.

Comment: Did you solve this?